# how to select first records with distinct foreign key after Join 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

i have 2 table 
ProductTBL(id,name,price)
imageTBL(id,ID_FK,imageName)
there is multi record in imageTBL for each Record in ProductTBL
i want to select only first image from imageTBL for each record 
i used ProductTBL left join imageTBL , but my query is not correct 
please help me to solve 
thnx
here is my incorrect Query:

```
create procedure test
as
begin
select * from ProductTBL as ProTBL
left join (select * from PicTBL as PicAll left join (select distinct ProductID_FK from PicTBL as picTblID))as pic
on ProTBL.ProductID = pic.ProductID_FK
where ProTBL.Pro_CatID = 4
end
```

Comment: What defines the "first" record?

Comment: Can we see sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your query doesn't match your tables and columns names. Second you need to define which record of PicTBL you need for each product (how do you define which image is the first image for a product). My response assume the first image is the image with the lower id.

A possible query is:

```
select * from ProductTBL as ProTBL 
left join ( select * from PicTBL PicTBLOne where not exists (   
    select * from PicTBL PicTblOther 
        where   PicTBLOne.ProductID_FK=PicTBLOther.ProductID_FK AND PicTBLOne.id > PicTBLOther.id 
    )
) as pic on ProTBL.ProductID = pic.ProductID_FK
```

You should use a view (materialized / indexed view) to back up the inner query and optimize the performance.

Answer (score 0):

try the following query:

```
SELECT picid, prodid, picture from 
(
SELECT picid, prodid, picture ,row_number() over (partition by prodid ORDER BY prodid desc) as prod
FROM t_picture
) t_prod_pic

where t_prod_pic.prod=1
```

it returns the first picture in from the picture table for all the products

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions the first one is going to return one image but not necessarily the first one. in the other solution you can select the image you want.
first solution:

```
SELECT  [id]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Price]
  ,Max(pic.imageName)
  FROM ProductTBL as ProTBL
  left join (select * from PicTBL) pic
  on ProTBL.ProductID = pic.ProductID_FK
  where ProTBL.Pro_CatID = 4
  group by id,Name,price
```

*second solution selecting the first image ordering descending by pic.name*

```
select * from
  (SELECT  [id]
     ,[Name]
     ,[Price]
     ,pic.imageName
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pic.imageName) AS RowNumber
     FROM  ProductTBL as ProTBL
      left join (select * from PicTBL) pic
     on ProTBL.ProductID = pic.ProductID_FK
     where ProTBL.Pro_CatID = 4
     ) XX
    where RowNumber = 1;
```

hope you find this handy.

Comment: thank you for help.that is worked correctly.your second solution was perfect.i test all answers and your second and Didier answer were handy and perfect for me